# Making my own accordion style toggle with jquery

Tags: jquery, event-bubbling

I have a var in js which holds a click action. This action is bound to a few different divs:

```
<div class="clickable"><div class="hidden">inner content 1</div></div>

<div class="clickable"><div class="hidden">inner content 2</div></div>

<div class="clickable"><div class="hidden">inner content 3</div></div>
```

The js looks like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var clicker = function(){

    $('.hidden').slideUp();

    $(this).children('.hidden').slideDown();

    $(this).unbind('click',clicker);
}


$('.clickable').bind('click',clicker);


});
```

The above code basically works. If i click a div.clickable it shows the hidden content. If I click another div.clickable, it hides the content I was just looking at and reveals another one. The problem however is that because of that unbind function inside 'clicker' anything I click loses its clicker functionality. I did this because the hidden content has clickable stuff, and anything I now click inside the hidden content triggers off 'clicker' again.

Whats the more intelligent approach to this without using the accordion plugins?

How can I check to see if a div has been bound to a function, and if not, rebind it or something of the sort? All I am looking for is to rebind the div.clickable to 'clicker' once its been closed ie another div.clickable .hidden is being looked at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just exclude the one you're clicking on in the [`.slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/), like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.clickable').click(function(){
    $('.hidden').not($(this).children()).slideUp();
    $(this).children('.hidden:hidden').slideDown();
  });
});
```

By using [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) we're excluding the current element in the `.hidden` ones to hide, and when showing children restricting it to only [`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) elements means we won't re-slide any that are already visible.

Another way to re-write it a bit more plainly is:

```
$(function(){
  $('.clickable').click(function(){
    $('.clickable').not(this).children('.hidden').slideUp();
    $(this).children('.hidden:hidden').slideDown();
  });
});
```

Or, if they all `.clickable` elements are siblings:

```
$(function(){
  $('.clickable').click(function(){
    $(this).children('.hidden:hidden').slideDown()
     .end().siblings('.clickable').children('.hidden').slideUp();
  });
});
```

Comment: @KeenLearner - and less binding :) I added some alternatives to make it a bit clearer what's happening, pick your flavor :)

Comment: correction NO binding! awesome. learned a lot from your help - cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var clicker = function(){

    $('.clickable').bind('click',clicker);

    $('.hidden').slideUp();

    $(this).children('.hidden').slideDown();

    $(this).unbind('click',clicker);
}


$('.clickable').bind('click',clicker);


});
```

Comment: This doesn't really solve any issues, children *would* still collapse their parent (if this worked), but you're double-binding then unbinding both all over again, so really this would have no net effect.